# Back and Forth Communication Issue with Python and Arduino

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, pyserial, duplex

I am developing a code that is suppose to take data from a load cell and based on that data it should control a motor. If the load cell reads a specific value the motor should rotate one direction, if it reads a different value it should go in the other direction. Right now if I apply a load to the sensor the motor will go in one direction, when the load is removed the motor will not go the other way. Instead it continues to go in the wrong direction. I am also having python save the data from the load cell to a csv file and because of that I have noticed that the load cell value stays at a high number like 117 newtons even when the force from the load cell is removed. Before having the communication between arduino and python the output of the sensor was spot on. I have read a little on duplexing and was thinking maybe there in lies my problem. Any help on why my python force value is wrong now would be great.

I have tried a different format to making my arduino code. Arduino Code 2 works, better, I can get the motor to respond to the inputs on the load cell, however as I print the data coming into python it does get a little screwed up. This does not affect my motor surprisingly though. I intend on keeping this incoming data for future use and was hoping that it could be cleaned up. For example lets say that I have 5 newtons of force on there it will display 5 newtons for a few seconds then it will spike to a random number for a couple instances then back to normal.

**Python**

```
import serial
import csv
import time
from time import localtime, strftime
import warnings
import serial.tools.list_ports


__author__ = 'Matt Munn'
arduino_ports = [
    p.device
    for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    if 'Arduino' in p.description
]
if not arduino_ports:
    raise IOError("No Arduino found - is it plugged in? If so, restart computer.")
if len(arduino_ports) > 1:
    warnings.warn('Multiple Arduinos found - using the first')

Arduino = serial.Serial(arduino_ports[0],9600,timeout=1)
time.sleep(2)


start_time=time.time()

Force = []
Actuator_Signal=[]

outputFileName = "Cycle_Pull_Test_#.csv"
outputFileName = outputFileName.replace("#", strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H %M %S", localtime()))

with open(outputFileName, 'w',newline='') as outfile:

    outfileWrite = csv.writer(outfile)

    while True:
        while (Arduino.inWaiting()==0):
            pass
        try:
            data = Arduino.readline()
            dataarray = data.decode().rstrip().split(',')
            Force = round(float(dataarray[0]),3)
            print (Force)

            if Force < 50:
                Arduino.write(b'u')
                print ('up')

            else: 
                Arduino.write(b'd')
                print('down')


        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit,IndexError,ValueError):
            pass

        outfileWrite.writerow([Force,"N"])
```

**Arduino**

```
#include <HX711_ADC.h>
#include "CytronMotorDriver.h"


// Configure the motor driver.
CytronMD motor(PWM_DIR, 3, 2);  // PWM = Pin 3, DIR = Pin 2.

int up = HIGH;
int down = LOW;
int dstate = up;
int python_direction = 0;
float interval = 12000;
float pretime= 0;
float curtime = 0; 



// LOAD CELL
//HX711 constructor (dout pin, sck pin)
HX711_ADC LoadCell(11, 12);
float force;  
float calforce;
float newtons;


// The setup routine runs once when you press reset.
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 LoadCell.begin();
 LoadCell.start(2000); // tare preciscion can be improved by adding a few seconds of stabilising time
 LoadCell.setCalFactor(100); // user set calibration factor (float)
}

// The loop routine runs over and over again forever.
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()>0){
    python_direction = Serial.read();
    Serial.print (python_direction);
    Serial.print (",");
  }
  LoadCell.update();
  force = LoadCell.getData();
  force = (force/285); // Force in (N) // 285 is conversion factor
  calforce = (-1.0389*force)+0.0181, // This is in lbs
  newtons = 4.45*calforce;



  receive from serial terminal for tare
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  char inByte = Serial.read();
  if (inByte == 't') LoadCell.tareNoDelay();
  }

unsigned long curtime = millis();


  if (python_direction == 'u'){
    motor.setSpeed(255);  // Run forward at full speed.

  }
  if (python_direction == 0){
    motor.setSpeed(0);  // Stop motor.

  }
  if (python_direction == 'd'){
    motor.setSpeed(-255);  // Run backward at full speed.


  }




  Serial.println(newtons);
}
```

**Arduino 2**

```
#include <HX711_ADC.h> // HX711 Library
#include "CytronMotorDriver.h"

// Configure the motor driver.
CytronMD motor(PWM_DIR, 3, 2);  // PWM = Pin 3, DIR = Pin 2.

int up = HIGH;
int down = LOW;
int dstate = up;
int python_direction = 0;
float interval = 12000;
float pretime= 0;
float curtime = 0;

HX711_ADC LoadCell(11, 12);

float force;  
float calforce;
float newtons;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  LoadCell.begin();
  LoadCell.start(2000); // tare preciscion can be improved by adding a few seconds of stabilising time
  LoadCell.setCalFactor(100.0); // user set calibration factor (float)


}

void loop() {
  LoadCell.update();

  forceRead();
  actuatorControl();


}void forceRead()
{
  force = LoadCell.getData();
  force = (force/285); // Force in (N) // 285 is conversion factor
  calforce = (-1.0389*force)+0.0181, // This is in lbs
  newtons = 4.45*calforce;
  Serial.println(newtons);


  //receive from serial terminal for tare
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  char inByte = Serial.read();
  if (inByte == 't') LoadCell.tareNoDelay();
  }
}

void actuatorControl(){

  if (Serial.available()>0){
    python_direction = Serial.read();
    Serial.print (python_direction);
    Serial.print (",");
  }
  if (python_direction == 'd'){
    motor.setSpeed(255);  // Run forward at full speed.

  }
  if (python_direction == 0){
    motor.setSpeed(0);  // Stop motor.

  }
  if (python_direction == 'u'){
    motor.setSpeed(-255);  // Run backward at full speed.


  }
}
```

Comment: The Arduino is checking for serial input in two different places.  In one place, it interprets the input as a direction, in the other place it interprets it as a possible tare command.  But there is absolutely no assurance that any character will be received in the right place.  So, you could have a 't' that gets used as an invalid direction, or a direction command that gets compared to 't' and then ignored completely.

Comment: I have played with removing that tare command and I still get the same result. I figured that that was an issue, but without a change in the outcome I couldn't say for sure it was the only cause of error.

Comment: I made a change to my arduino code and it now preforms better, but it is still not great. I explained the current issue in the description of my issue above.